# JavaScript Mobile number verification for Turkey

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to check for mobile number entry via JavaScript RegEx but I am having difficulty on construction the proper query. What I want is to validate mobile numbers only. The format I require is : 
5(0/3/4)X XXX XXXX
including the spaces.

For example;
532 123 4567 will be valid while
532 1234567 is invalid. Also
458 123 4567 is invalid.

To clarify the rules are:

1. First digit must be 5
2. Second digit must be either 0 or 3 or 4 or 5
3. Followed by any digit according to the following rules:

   - If previous digit is 0 this digit must be (5, 6 or 7)
   - If previous digit is 3 this digit can be (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
   - If previous digit is 4 this digit can be (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
   - If previous digit is 5 this digit can be (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
4. Single space
5. Any 3-digit number
6. Single space
7. Any 4-digit number

Code I am using is as follows:

```
function isPhone(phone) {
    var pattern = [PATTERN HERE];
    return pattern.test(phone);
}
```

Which pattern should I use for validation?

Regards.

Comment: I would suggest not worrying about the spaces.

Comment: Possibly, but that looks neater and increases readability.

Comment: Readability is not your site users' problem. If the number will work when dialed, the spaces don't matter.

Comment: Mobile number validation can sometimes be complicated. Have a look to [Google's libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple regex to match your exact rules are:

```
^5(0[5-7]|[3-5]\d) \d{3} \d{4}$
```

[Test it on regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/X5d4iz/1)

Note that if you are validating user input, you should allow any input that is usable without requiring formatting. In that case you should make the spaces optional:

```
^5(0[5-7]|[3-5]\d) ?\d{3} ?\d{4}$
```

Comment: That looks pretty impressive and works on the site but when I deploy it into my page it does not work properly.

Comment: @user3021830 In that case you're implementing it wrong. The regex works as evident by the regex101 link - it's impossible for me to help you further without seeing how you implement it.

Comment: @user3021830 [Seems to work fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/LbSeh1L.png)

Comment: I m terribly sorry. Copy-paste error in my code mislead me. It truly works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is **[the regex](https://regex101.com/r/gfJU2M/2)** you need:

```
/^5(0[5-7]|[3-5]\d)\s\d{3}\s\d{4}$/gm
```

This is how should be your function:

```
function isPhone(phone) {
    var pattern = /^5(0[5-7]|[3-5]\d)\s\d{3}\s\d{4}$/gm;
    return pattern.test(phone);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const regex = /^5(0[5-7]|[3-5]\d)\s\d{3}\s\d{4}$/gm;
const str = `532 123 4567
509 457 5879
551 123 1478
532 1234567
458 123 4567
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```